# Can I programatically add/remove bookmarks to my Google Chrome profile from code running on an AWS server?

Tags: google-chrome

I know Chrome bookmarks are stored locally, on the computer. But since Chrome profiles can be configured to sync with your Google account, I'm wondering if I can programatically add/remove bookmarks to my profile from code running on a server in AWS. Then Chrome would just sync those like normal.